# Why all asp.net mvc samples on the net reference the DAL in UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

may be I got it all wrong but in all the companies I have worked we never added a reference to the Dal in the UI layer (winforms-Web)
I am new to web but a seasoned winform-wcf developer,however I am struggling with the concept of having the dal being referenced in the UI.

In a big team with no proper supervision is a recipe for disaster.

Why not have 2 composition roots

```
 1)WebUI just services classes (not wcf) when using wcf composition root is in there

 2)within the services that we inject there the repository.
```

Am i missing the obvious?

thanks

UPDATED

In all the samples I see they all use DI (Unity-Autofac-Nject etc..) and they wire up the repository via interface,which also requires the concrete class,hence the reference to the DAL.Can this be done in the service layer?

Comment: Because they are samples not production code. Using DI in sample code is a recipe for complete confusion unless it's actually a DI / Repository sample.

Comment: thanks for your time and reply. I have updated the question.Yes they all use DI which in order to set it up requires referencing the dal. Can this set up be done in the service layer etc..

Comment: if you are using DI it cannot be done in service layer since all the dependencies registered on application start which basically initializes MVC (UI)  application. By the way concrete service implementations as well may be injected

Comment: IN that case you'd typically be passing in a Repository to a controller via constructor injection. So you have to do it in the UI layer for simple DI MVC because that's where the controllers live. Ultimately you're going to get an "it depends" answer here. There's a myriad of ways of doing things but as you say we're talking sample code here so they will typically be based around a demoing a particular concept not necessarily best practice.

Comment: lets talk "real world" then which in this case is the same.If I understand what you are saying because the composition root happens when you initialize the MVC app ,you must reference the DAL to inject the repositories (DI).Conclusion because of this it's become a standard practice in real world project to reference the DAL in mvc UI and it's up to the developer no to use the dal directly.mmmmm

Comment: You can use some proxy project: a separate project that has references to all the dependencies and contains all the registration logic. Then your UI is going to reference only this project without any other references to actual implementations

Comment: @AlexArt is the any example anywhere of this implementaion

Comment: @developer9969, to compose dependencies of your application you also need connection strings to dabatase for your repositories. So, when you compose your application in ASP.NET mvc app for example you can use plain old Web.Config ;) Also as an authorative in DI topic Mark Seemann wrote in his excellent book - "Dependency Injection in .NET" you must put your Composition Root as close to application's entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to inject dependencies without referencing data access layer from the UI. You have to add a transversal Utils or Helpers project that will resolve all dependencies across the project.

In this explanation I'll use Unity for DI. I'll walk your through it in a couple of steps:

First, create an Utils project. This project will be transversal to all the layers. Add this static class with an extension method for IUnityContainer:

```
// This class will resolve all dependencies across the project
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    // This method will resolve all dependencies
    public static void ResolveDependencies(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.ResolveBusinessLayerDependencies();
        container.ResolveDataAccessLayerDependencies();
    }
}
```

This will force you to create both methods: ResolveBusinessLayerDependencies and ResolveDataAccessLayerDependencies in the container.

Second, you should go to your business logic project (here, you should be able to access the interfaces and implementations of this layer). Add a new static class like this:

```
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    public static void ResolveBusinessLayerDependencies(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLayerClass, BusinessLayerClass>();
    }
}
```

Do the same for your data access project:

```
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    public static void ResolveDataAccessLayerDependencies(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IDataAccessLayerClass, DataAccessLayerClass>();
    }
}
```

Now in the UnityConfig.cs, the method RegisterTypes would be something like:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
      container.ResolveDependencies();
}
```

This is one way I've find useful to use DI without referencing all layers from the main project

Comment: that makes sense and I like the fact of using a dll that can be  called by others